# Create a substring with start and end in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, substring

For my school project, I need to programm a gps-module. The module sends me the ASCII's via the UART and I already got them into one big string. 
The gps-module sends a very big message, but i only need one part:

```
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
$GPGLL,4841.9388,N,01600.3418,E,000016.015,V,N*48
$GPZDA,000016.015,22,08,1999,,*55
$GPGSV,1,1,01,28,-90,000,33*66
$PERDCR,11,0,0,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.0,0,0,0.0,0,0,255,0,F,999*43
$PERDCR,1,32540,0,817,16,0,52,0,91,0,0,0,33,0x00,*41
$GPRMC,000017.015,V,4841.9388,N,01600.3418,E,0.00,0.00,220899,,,N*76
**$GPGGA,000017.015,4841.9388,N,01600.3418,E,0,00,0.0,277.9,M,0.0,M,,*6E** <-this part
```

The bold part can be anywhere in this package. I've saved the package in

```
char data[507];
```

How can i get the data from $GPGGA - *6E?
Note: The data changes and the position of the GPGGA-Package changes. The only two parameters, that don't change are the starting string:"$GPGGA" and the length of the GPGGA-message, in this case: 70

Comment: You cannot highlight code. So, what have you tried? Why is it not working? Sorry, but we are no "gimme teh codez" site, if that was your question.

Comment: You can find a pointer to `"$GPGGA,"` by using `ptr = strstr(data, "$GPGGA,");` but please allocate a bigger buffer for `char data[507];` not so tight, perhaps twice the size for now.

Comment: use `strlen` to check the length of the string is 70 and use `strstr` to verify that the string begins with **$GPGGA**

Comment: Having found the location of the field, do not be so sure of its length. Evaluate every sub-field to avoid the possibility of truncating the data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [strstr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) to find the first occurrence of a string. You could also use strstr to find the end but since you know the length is always 70 you don't have to search for that.

```
// Proof of concept (uncompiled)
char* start = strstr(data, "$GPGGA");
strncpy(message, start, 70);
```

Reference: [strncpy/strncpy_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy)

Comment: How can a "proof" not even be tested? And `strncpy_s` is a non-standard function.

Comment: A proof of concept is about the idea, not if it works or not. I added that comment in case I made typo or, as you pointed out, use a non-standard function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks joell!!!
I haven't thougt about the function strncpy. What I've tried in the beginning was that i got the position of a "$" and then the position+1="G", position+2="P" and so on(with if's). And I knew it wouldn't work correctly because I'm working with ISR's and the BAUD-Rate=9600, so my code would change to often for so many if's.

Thank you very much for all your responses, especially Mister joell! 
Note: start must be of type int (position is an integer value)